# how to wait to force subroutine to show widget before it continue to next line

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I have this subroutine:

```
def checkout_button_handler(self):
   self.processing_label.show()
   self.qry_db()
   self.processing_label.hide() 
   return
```

when I call it, `processing_label` never shows, and it starts querying the db.
How can I force showing this label before it moves to the next line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Processing pending events](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) before querying the db might help:

```
self.processing_label.show()
QtGui.qApp.processEvents() # or QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()
self.qry_db()
```